# while typing email ID in textbox it should validate the format and display tick image using MVC3 RAZOR

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, email, razor

I want to validate the Email id format is correct or not

While typing Emailid in Razor textbox it should display the tick mark if it is in correct format

Otherwise error message should display below the textbox.

Please guide me.. how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom validation attribute:

```
public class EmailAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string Pattern = @"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$";
    private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        var input = value as string;
        return ((input != null) && (_regex.Match(input).Length > 0));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRegexRule(
            base.ErrorMessage,
            Pattern
        );
    }
}
```

that will be used to decorate your view model property with:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a valid email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and then assuming you have a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

you could just write a simple script to plug into the unobtrusive validation framework and achieve what you are looking for. You would then create a separate javascript file (email.js) with the following contents:

```
$(function () {
    var settings = $('form').data('validator').settings;
    settings.onkeyup = function (element) {
        $(element).nextAll('.tick').remove();
        if ($(element).valid()) {
            $(element).after('<span class="tick">&#10004;</span>');
        }
    };
});
```

and the last step would of course be to include the 3 scripts to your page to enable client side validation:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/email.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: hey darin, i thought you were now against answering any questions that don't offer some insight as to how they had tackled the issue themselves (i.e. what have you tried so far) :-). +1 anyway!!

Comment: Hey @jimtollan, that depends on my mood.

Comment: careful, you're almost sounding human now, which can't surely be possible given your prolific rate here on SO :-)... enjoy the weekend..

Comment: Your code is working perfectly, but when I completely delete the email id using Backspace, tick mark is displaying......

Comment: @raj2sekar1, that's because the regular expression used in my answer allows for an empty value. You could add the `[Required]` attribute if the email field is required.

Comment: yeah, its working but I need to display the error message below the txtbox and tick mark in rigth to textbox itself